# Evitar mensajes de error "redundantes"

Tags: php, php7, class

Tengo una clase que crea una tabla HTML basada en `<div>`s. Para darle formato es obligatorio para cada fila y para cada celda establecer el atributo `class`. Si no se establece ese atributo se establece uno predeterminado. Cuando NO se establece ese atributo y se usa el predeterminado lanzo un error (`trigger_error("mensaje", E_USER_WARNING);`). El problema lo tengo cuando debo lanzar el error para las celdas que no tienen la clase asignada: se muestran muchos mensajes iguales y redundantes dependiendo, claramente, de la cantidad de celdas. Para no repetir errores, hice lo siguiente: declaré un `private array` y un nuevo método:

```
    private $html_class_warning = [
        "table",
        "title",
        "header",
        "header_cell",
        "body",
        "row",
        "cell",
        "footer",
        "footer_cell"
    ];

    private function checkHtmlClassWarning(string $section = "")
    {
        if (in_array($section, $this->html_class_warning)) {
            unset($this->html_class_warning[array_search($section, $this->html_class_warning)]);
            trigger_error("No '$section' class defined; using default: '" . self::HTML_TABLE_CLASSES[$section] . "' (see HTML rendered code)", E_USER_WARNING);
        }
    }
```

Cada vez que se muestra un aviso para un elemento, ese elemento se quita del array `$html_class_warning` entonces consigo mostrar el mensaje una sola vez. Obvio que podría ser mas específico y señalar fila y columna.

El código funciona pero me preguntaba por otras formas de resolver la cuestión.

Graceas!

PD: ya sé que debería usar una versión mas reciente de PHP, pero esto es lo que hay así que no se molesten en avisarme al respecto. Igual se lo agradezco a quien lo quisiera sugerir.